# mysql query to workout friends of friends who are not in my friends list

Tags: php, mysql

I have a friends table that keeps track of relationships in my db - I have put together a query with subquery that gets the profile info from friends of friends

my friends table looks like the below - id's go in twice both ways. I am user with an id of 1 - my friends would be 5 & 3

```
rel 1 | rel 2
--------------
1     |    5
5     |    1
3     |    5
5     |    3
1     |    3
3     |    1
```

My query looks like

```
SELECT user_id, first_name, last_name, email, town, county, profile_img_small 
FROM sign_up 
WHERE user_id IN (SELECT DISTINCT f.rel2 FROM friends f
WHERE f.rel1 IN (SELECT f2.rel2 FROM friends f2 WHERE f2.rel1 = '$my_id') AND f.rel2 !    = '$my_id') ORDER BY first_name ASC, last_name ASC
```

The problem with this is that the script is meant to suggest people you might know but still includes people who are in my friends list.

How do I pull the same query excluding users I am already friends with

Comment: just to address that - not every answer has been correct or applicable but I honestly appreciate every single bit of input I get from stack. I will of course make sure I accept everything where poss.

Answer (score 2):

Try this instead:

```
SELECT *
FROM sign_up
WHERE user_id NOT IN
(
   SELECT rel1 FROM friends WHERE rel2 = '$my_id'
   UNION 
   SELECT rel2 FROM friends WHERE rel1 = '$my_id'
)
```

Answer (score 0):

The query I went with is below - I basically added another subquery at the end

```
SELECT user_id, first_name, last_name, email, town, county, profile_img_small 
FROM sign_up 
WHERE user_id IN (SELECT DISTINCT f.rel2 FROM friends f
WHERE f.rel1 IN (SELECT f2.rel2 FROM friends f2 WHERE f2.rel1 = '$my_id') AND f.rel2 != '$my_id') AND user_id NOT IN (SELECT rel2 FROM friends WHERE rel1 = '$my_id') ORDER BY first_name ASC, last_name ASC
```